# How to stop AnythingSlider when Flowplayer clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flowplayer, anythingslider

I'm using the Flowplayer plugin inside the [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) control. I'd like to stop the slider from moving to the next slide when the user clicks to interact with the Flowplayer. I've tried the following but the slider continues to move to the next slide; the .click() call on the #start-stop item didn't work either. I'd like it to stop when the user clicks on any part of the Flowplayer, though in this case I tested it for the onStart.

```
$f("vid", "flowplayer-3.2.1.swf", {
    clip: {
      autoPlay: false,
      autoBuffering: true,
      onStart: function(clip) {
        //$('#start-stop').click();
        $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider.startStop(false);
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you get the latest version of [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-1-4/), then try this:

```
$f("vid", "flowplayer-3.2.1.swf", {
 clip: {
  autoPlay: false,
  autoBuffering: true,
  onStart: function(clip) {
   $('.anythingSlider').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);
  }
 }
});
```