# How to stop anythingSlider

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I have several sliders on the same page and but don't show all at once.  I would like to be able to stop a slider and remove the animation by an event function.  As it works right now, if I hide a slider, it still runs in the background, the dom shows the images rotating and the url parameters change.

I've seen this question, but it did not work for me: [How to stop AnythingSlider when Flowplayer clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827312/how-to-stop-anythingslider-when-flowplayer-clicked)

This is also somewhat similar, but I want to remove the slider instead of restarting: [AnythingSlider: how to restart slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879060/anythingslider-how-to-restart-slideshow)

```
function stopAnythingSlider() {
  // I receive `TypeError: $(".anythingSlider").data("AnythingSlider") is undefined`
  // $('.anythingSlider').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);
}
```

*Edit: 
I used the id of my list instead of `.anythingSlider` and that seems to be working,

```
 $('#idOfList').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);
```

Comment: remove is simple `$('.anythingSlider').eq( indexValue).remove()`. Just fill in the `indexValue` for slider you want removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to specify the id of the list I want to stop

```
function stopAnythingSlider() {
   $('#idOfList').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);
}
```

If I want to stop multiple lists with the same class:

```
function stopAnythingSliderMultiple() {
  $('.anythingSlider ul.hideTheseOnly').each(function() {
    $(this).data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);
  });
}
```